# Fetched data from mvvm is not updated in recycler view on first visit

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

PreAdmissionList.java

```
public class PreAdmissionList extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterApprovalList.OnItemClickListener {

    private BasicInfoViewModel basicInfoViewModel;
    private AdapterApprovalList adapterApprovalList;
    private RecyclerView rvApprovalList;

    public PreAdmissionList() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pre_admission_list, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        view.findViewById(R.id.fab_add_new_admission).setOnClickListener(this);

        rvApprovalList = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_approval_list);


        basicInfoViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(BasicInfoViewModel.class);
        basicInfoViewModel.init();
        basicInfoViewModel.getApprovalList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<ModelBasicInfo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<ModelBasicInfo> modelBasicInfos) {
                adapterApprovalList.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        initRecyclerView();

    }

    private void initRecyclerView() {
        adapterApprovalList = new AdapterApprovalList(this,basicInfoViewModel.getApprovalList().getValue());
        rvApprovalList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvApprovalList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        rvApprovalList.setAdapter(adapterApprovalList);
    }


}
```

AdapterApprovalList.java

```
public class AdapterApprovalList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterApprovalList.ALViewHolder>{

    private Context context;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    private List<ModelBasicInfo> modelBasicInfoList;

    public AdapterApprovalList(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener,List<ModelBasicInfo> modelBasicInfoList) {

        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
        this.modelBasicInfoList=modelBasicInfoList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ALViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.template_approval_list_item,parent,false);
        return new ALViewHolder(view,onItemClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ALViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ModelBasicInfo basicInfo = modelBasicInfoList.get(position);
        StringBuilder fullName = new StringBuilder();
        fullName.append(basicInfo.getFirstName()).append(" ");
        fullName.append(basicInfo.getMiddleName()).append(" ");
        fullName.append(basicInfo.getLastName()).append(" ");

        holder.fullName.setText(fullName);

        holder.id.setText("RKC00"+String.valueOf(basicInfo.getId()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modelBasicInfoList.size();
    }

    static class ALViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
        TextView fullName,id;
        public ALViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView,OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener) {
            super(itemView);
            this.mOnItemClickListener = mOnItemClickListener;
            fullName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_text_full_name);
            id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_text_approval_id);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mOnItemClickListener.onApprovalItemClick(getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onApprovalItemClick(int position);
    }


}
```

BasicInfoViewModel.java

```
public class BasicInfoViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private BasicInfoRepo basicInfoRepo;
    private MutableLiveData<List<ModelBasicInfo>> approvalList;

    public void init(){
        if(approvalList != null){
            return;
        }
        basicInfoRepo = BasicInfoRepo.getInstance();
        approvalList = basicInfoRepo.getApprovalList();
    }

    public LiveData<List<ModelBasicInfo>> getApprovalList(){
        return approvalList;
    }

    public void insertBasicInfo(ModelBasicInfo modelBasicInfo){
        basicInfoRepo.insertData(modelBasicInfo);
    }

    public void updateApprovalStatus(int id){
        basicInfoRepo.updateStatus(id);
    }


}
```

BasicInfoRepo.java

```
public class BasicInfoRepo {

    private static BasicInfoRepo instance;

    static ConnectionClass connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
    private List<ModelBasicInfo> approvalList = new ArrayList<>();


    public static BasicInfoRepo getInstance(){
        if(instance== null){
            instance = new BasicInfoRepo();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<ModelBasicInfo>> getApprovalList(){
        loadApprovalList();
        MutableLiveData<List<ModelBasicInfo>> mList = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mList.setValue(approvalList);
        return mList;
    }

    private void loadApprovalList() {
        LoadApprovalList loadApprovalList = new LoadApprovalList();
        loadApprovalList.execute();

    }

    public void insertData(ModelBasicInfo modelBasicInfo){
        InsertBasicInfo insertBasicInfo = new InsertBasicInfo();
        insertBasicInfo.execute(modelBasicInfo);

    }

    public void updateStatus(int id){
        UpdateBasicInfo updateBasicInfo = new UpdateBasicInfo();
        updateBasicInfo.execute(id);
    }



    private static class InsertBasicInfo extends AsyncTask<ModelBasicInfo,Integer,String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(ModelBasicInfo... model) {
            String result = null;

//            Log.i("Testing db",lists[0].get(0).getFirstName());
            try{
                Connection connection = connectionClass.CONN();
                if(connection==null){
                    result = "Error in connection !!!";
                }else{

                    //Date object
                    Date date= new Date();
                    //getTime() returns current time in milliseconds
                    long time = date.getTime();
                    //Passed the milliseconds to constructor of Timestamp class
                    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(time);

                    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into PreAdmissionDetails values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                    ps.setString(1,model[0].getFirstName());
                    ps.setString(2,model[0].getMiddleName());
                    ps.setString(3,model[0].getLastName());
                    ps.setString(4,model[0].getMotherName());
                    ps.setDate(5, java.sql.Date.valueOf(model[0].getDateOfBirth()));
                    ps.setString(6,model[0].getMobileNo());
                    ps.setInt(7,0);
                    ps.setInt(8,0);
                    ps.setBoolean(9,false);
                    ps.setTimestamp(10, ts);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    result = "Submitted Successfully !!!";

                }

            }catch (Exception ex){
                Log.e("sqlerror",ex.toString());
                result=ex.getMessage();
            }
            Log.e("sqlerror","result : "+result);
            return result;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }

    }

    private static class UpdateBasicInfo extends AsyncTask<Integer,Integer,String>{


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

            String result = null;

            try{
                Connection connection = connectionClass.CONN();
                if(connection==null){
                    result = "Error in connection !!!";
                }else{

                    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE PreAdmissionDetails SET STATUS=? WHERE id=?");
                    ps.setInt(1,0);
                    ps.setInt(2,integers[0]);

                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    result = "Updated Successfully !!!";

                }

            }catch (Exception ex){
                Log.e("sqlerror",ex.toString());
                result=ex.getMessage();
            }
            Log.e("sqlerror","result : "+result.toString());
            return result;

        }
    }

    private class LoadApprovalList extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String result = null;
            try{
                Connection connection = connectionClass.CONN();
                if(connection==null){
                    result = "Error in connection !!!";
                }else{

                    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from preadmissiondetails");
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    approvalList.clear();
                    while (rs.next()) {
                    approvalList.add(new ModelBasicInfo(rs.getInt(1),
                            rs.getString(2),
                            rs.getString(3),
                            rs.getString(4),
                            rs.getString(5),
                            rs.getString(6),
                            rs.getString(7),
                            rs.getInt(8),
                            rs.getInt(9),
                            rs.getBoolean(10)));}

                    result = "Fetched Successfully !!!";

                }

            }catch (Exception ex){
                Log.e("sqlerror",ex.toString());
                result=ex.getMessage();
            }
            Log.e("sqlerror","result : "+result.toString());

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is here that when I open the app no items in the recycler view, Firsty I thought may be slow internet it will fetch data in after some time but it doesn't show data. But when I navigate to some other fragments and return to the preadmission list it shows data.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
public MutableLiveData<List<ModelBasicInfo>> getApprovalList(){
    loadApprovalList();
    MutableLiveData<List<ModelBasicInfo>> mList = new MutableLiveData<>();
    mList.setValue(approvalList);
    return mList;
}
```

`loadApprovalList()` launches an AsyncTask, which is an asynchronous operation (in other words, it takes time to produce a result). The `getApprovalList()` method doesn't just halt right there and wait for `loadApprovalList()` to complete. It continues right along and returns an empty list the first time it executes. But by the second time it executes, `approvalList` now has a value because the AsyncTask has completed. So it returns the correct data that second time it executes. It executes a second time when you return to your Fragment because the `init` block in your ViewModel is executing a second time at that point.

The solution is to make `approvalList` a LiveData. That way, when the AsyncTask updates approvalList, your ViewModel can observe the change. Your ViewModel should observe `approvalList` in your Repository, just like how your Fragment is observing the `getApprovalList()` method in your ViewModel.